# Interpret the variable in the given string

Tags: php, string, variables, constants

Is there a way to interpret variables, constants and arrays in a string?
Unfortunately, I have no influence on the creation of the string.

`just a $test, for myself`

or

`please use path dirname(__FILE__) for`

or

`i like $['fruits'] on mondays`

Comment: _I have no influence on the creation of the string._ How can you change anything if you can't touch the code?

Comment: The strings come from a configuration file.

Comment: There's no built-in function to do this, so you need to work with **regular expressions**. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19563063/1529324) you can find a good start. However in your case it will be more complex as you're also looking for methods such as `dirname`